# Need to convert this For loop to while

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to convert for loop to while loop in python and I am not very sure how to do it. Need some help here, thanks! This is what I am working with :

#FOR
#aplicacion que imprima tablas de multiplicar desde la tabla que yo quiera hasta la tabla que yo quiera elijiendo desde que multiplicacion mostrar hasta que multiplicacion mostar

```
desde=int(input("desde tabla quiere saber...?"))
hasta=int(input("hasta que tabla quiere saber...?"))
comenzando=int(input("desde que multiplicacion quiere ver?...?"))
multi=int(input("hasta que multiplicacion quiere ver?...?"))

for i in range(desde,hasta+1):
    for a in range(comenzando,multi+1):
        rta= i*a
```

Comment: what is not clear ? why dont u try writing the loop and checking if it works.. then ask your doubts ?

Answer (score 2):

This is source

```
desde=int(input("desde tabla quiere saber...?"))
hasta=int(input("hasta que tabla quiere saber...?"))
comenzando=int(input("desde que multiplicacion quiere ver?...?"))
multi=int(input("hasta que multiplicacion quiere ver?...?"))
x = desde
while x <= hasta:
    a = comenzando
    while a <= multi:
        rta = x*a

        a += 1
    x += 1
print(rta)
```

Answer (score -1):

`for` is perfect for the loops you have, because you know the start and end and there are a fixed number of loops. `while` is more appropriate for loops where they can run varying number of loops, e.g. prompting repeatedly until a valid email address is entered.

```
i = desde
while i <= hasta:

    a = comenzando
    while a <= multi:
        rta = i*a

        a += 1
    i += 1
```

This can be done as one `while` loop, but there would be calculations to work out the `a` and `i` values, using divide and modulo/remainder.